# mysql use index with < or null

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table (http_request) and I have created a compound index on:
processed_at
processing_uuid_expires_at
prio

Unfortunately the index is not used when I check processing_uuid_expires_at for < or NULL:

```
select * from  `http_requests`
where (`processing_uuid_expires_at` is null or `processing_uuid_expires_at` < '2021-03-09 11:35:12')
and `processed_at` is null
order by `prio` desc
limit 100;
```

It is only used when I have just one of the two or checks:

```
select * from  `http_requests`
where `processing_uuid_expires_at` is null
and `processed_at` is null
order by `prio` desc
limit 100;
```

Is there some way to make a query that checks for < OR null and that uses the index?
I also tried to force the index, but the query is still as slow as without it.

Comment: Tip: You only need backticks on column names that conflict with MySQL reserved keywords. These don't, you can skip it.

Comment: @tadman - you also must use backticks if the column name contains spaces

Comment: @BerndBuffen What kind of a monster puts spaces in their column names!? (Also, true, just saying.)

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.  (There are many possible reasons for what you are seeing.)